# pythons socket.sendto third argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I'm using python socket module, and I read that you can use either 2 or 3 arguments when using `socket.sendto()` command. you can specify address and message, but you can also send flags.
I was wondering what these flags are? I couldn't find any information about it. what happens when you send them? what is the default value? (when you don't specify a flag) what do they do?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Python documentation says, you have to go to [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto) for this information.  (The flags should be variables in the `socket` module with the same names that they have in C.)

Comment: Went there, though I didn't understand quite what the use is, it seems quite random.

Comment: @IdoKadosh: They are important in special use cases, but yes: there’s a reason the default is not to use any.